# complete form validation in php

Tags: php, validation

I have this php code associated with a database and I need here to make a complete email and name validation 
based on this code how can I do that because my code has some issues here

1)name key doesn't have (//) or any symbols to be a correct name

2)email key is valid email because what we did here just make ensure that there is @ symbol and if I type the email hhhh@hhh.com or even without( .com ) it will be valid also ?!!

```
if(array_key_exists("submit",$_POST)){
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456789","users");

  if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    die("There is a problem in connecting to database");
  }

  if(!$_POST['name']){
    $error .="<p>Your Full name is required</p><br>";
  }

  if(!$_POST['email']){
    $error .="<p>Your email address is required</p><br>";
  }

  if(!$_POST['password']){
    $error .="<p>Your password is required</p><br>";
  }

  if($error !=""){
    $error = "<p>There were errors in your form</p><br>".$error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't link to external sites with code. Paste the code here. And please rephrase/rewrite your questions, because they make absolutely no sense in their current form

Comment: I have just put the form validation that I have used

Comment: Is what you want to know HOW to make sure the name and email doesn't contain invalid characters, and that the email is a valid email? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes ! that is what I need

Comment: Have you tried / searched anything to solve this yourself?

Comment: Yes of course but it really didn't work well with my code I tried this
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp
really I need a correct method matched with my code

Comment: So, what's wrong with that? That should work and is nowhere to be found in the code you posted.

Comment: It didn't work with me as when I enter email like ggg@ggg.com or name like ggg/// it will not show any error messages

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for the validation:

```
 function filtervariable($string,$type,$method) {
    //function for sanitizing variables using PHPs built-in filter methods
    $validEmail = false;

    if ($method == 'sanitize') {
        $filtermethod = 'FILTER_SANITIZE_';
    } elseif ($method == 'validate') {
        $filtermethod = 'FILTER_VALIDATE_';
    } else {
        return;
    }
    switch ($type) {
        case 'email':
        case 'string':
        case 'number_int':
        case 'int':
        case 'special_chars':
        case 'url':
        $filtertype = $filtermethod.strtoupper($type);
        break;
    }

    if ($filtertype == 'FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL' && !empty($string)) {
        list($local,$domain) = explode('@',$string);

        $localLength = strlen($local);
        $domainLength = strlen($domain);

        $checkLocal = explode('.',$domain);

        if (($localLength > 0 && $localLength < 65) && ($domainLength > 3 && $domainLength < 256) && (checkdnsrr($domain,'MX') || checkdnsrr($domain,'A') || ($checkLocal[1] == 'loc' || $checkLocal[1] == 'dev' || $checkLocal[1] == 'srv'))) { // check for "loc, dev, srv" added to cater for specific problems with local setups
            $validEmail = true;
        } else {
            $validEmail = false;
        }
    }
    if (($filtertype == 'FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL' && $validEmail) || $filtertype != 'FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL') {
        return filter_var($string, constant($filtertype));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:
`$email = filtervariable($registeremail,'email','validate');`

It will return "true" on success and "false" on failure.

Comment: Please can you explain your answer ?

Comment: Dear junkfoodjunkie,
you mean that I can put this function any where in this mine php code ?!
also should I use 
$email = filtervariable($registeremail,'email','validate'); as you did 
or 
$_POST['email']=filtervariable($registeremail,'email','validate');

Comment: You either put the function at the bottom of the php-file above, or in an included file with PHP-functions, whereever, as long as it's available in the file where you do the validation. And you should really read some basic PHP-tutorials.

Comment: Thanks to you I will